# Is it just me or are there a lot more unanswered questions nowadays

Tags: support, questions

When I regularely logged in a few months ago, there would hardly be any unanswered questions on the front page. However, I logged in yesterday and today and I'm seeing tons of unanswered questions. So I'm wondering if anything has been changed how the front page displays questions.

It seems that the frontpage shows a lot more unanswered questions. Has that recently been changed?

Comment: I think, they've just tweaked the system to show more of unanswered questions on front page.

Comment: @YOU - this the the answer, it shouldn't be a comment.

Comment: @ripper234, I think I need some proves (links) to post it as answer.

Comment: The quality of the questions seems to have deteriorated drastically too.

Comment: I have noticed this too,  especially on topics like Database Design or Powershell.  Also,  there are a lot more questions that I can't answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/

Indeed that is the case, the front page algorithm has changed dramatically to *favor* unanswered questions and also to show you unanswered questions in your areas of interest.

Comment: That's very good actually. I was afraid that maybe a lot of "question answering" people were spreading their "question answering" time over different Stack Exchange sites that also coincide with some area of their interest/expertise. Like a software developer that in his spare time likes Boardgames/Photography/English language.

Answer (score 3):

Another reason for having unanswered question is the over popularity of SO.

With exponential growth of SOs popularity, it is inviting a lot of  blunt users. People would be reluctant to answer those questions. Some of them may face closing, but others just pass by, unanswered.